# builtins.KeyError KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS' (Flask-python)

Tags: mysql, python, sqlalchemy, flask

Soy un estudiante. Llevo horas intentando solucionar este error y no encuentro la manera de hacerlo:

Este es el error completo:

```
builtins.KeyError
KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1994, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "D:\Disenos\Apuntes Master\Marco_Programación\apuntes_programacion\Ejercicios Flask\imdb\app.py", line 138, in signup
my_user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 498, in __get__
return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
return self.registry()
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 990, in __call__
return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2829, in __call__
return self.class_(**local_kw)
File "C:\Users\Marco Alarcón\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 144, in __init__
track_modifications = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']
KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

Aquí dejo el app.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, flash, session
from forms import User_form, New_movie, Search_form, Perfil_form
from models import User, db, Movie
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import hashlib
import math
import os
import time
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/img/portadas/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'asd@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True

mail = Mail(app)

LIMITE_PELICULAS = 5

@app.route("/")
def login():
    form = User_form()
    if request.args.get('email') and request.args.get('password1'):
        email = request.args.get('email')
        password = hashlib.md5(request.args.get('password1').encode('UTF-8')).hexdigest()
        my_user = User.query.filter_by(email=email, password=password).first()
        if my_user:
            # Existe
            session['user'] = my_user.id
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            # No Existe
            flash('El usuario o contraseña no está registrado.')
    return render_template('items/login.html', form=form)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
        filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route("/peliculas/", methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={'pag': 1})
@app.route("/peliculas/<int:pag>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dashboard(pag):
    form = New_movie()
    form_search = Search_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # Movemos la imagen a staticgg
            file = request.files['image']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                hora_unix = int(time.time())
                ruta = str(hora_unix) + filename
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], ruta))
            else:
                flash('Debe ser una imagen.')
            # Guardamos la info en la base de datos
            my_movie = Movie(request.form['name'], request.form['year'], request.form['score'], ruta, session['user'])
            db.session.add(my_movie)
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Añadido correctamente', 'success')
            except:
                db.session.rollback()
        else:
            #mostramos errores
            errores = form.errors.items()
            for campo, mensajes in errores:
                for mensaje in mensajes:
                    flash(mensaje, 'danger')
    movies = Movie.query.limit(LIMITE_PELICULAS * pag).offset(LIMITE_PELICULAS * (pag - 1)).all()
    num_movies = Movie.query.count()
    num_paginas = math.ceil(num_movies / LIMITE_PELICULAS)
    # Obtenemos el usuario
    my_user = User.query.filter_by(id=session['user']).first()
    return render_template('items/dashboard.html', form=form, movies=movies, num_paginas=num_paginas, LIMITE_PELICULAS=LIMITE_PELICULAS, form_search=form_search, user=my_user)

@app.route("/search/<ordenar>")
def search(ordenar):
    movies = False
    form = New_movie()
    form_search = Search_form()

    if ordenar == 'year':
        movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.year)
    elif ordenar == 'name':
        movies = Movie.query.order_by(Movie.name)

    return render_template('items/dashboard.html', movies=movies, form=form, form_search=form_search, num_paginas=0)


@app.route("/filter")
def filter():
    form = New_movie()
    form_search = Search_form()
    name = request.args.get('name')
    year = request.args.get('year')
    movies = Movie.query.filter(Movie.name.like(f'%{name}%')).filter(Movie.year.like(f'%{year}%')).all()

    return render_template('items/dashboard.html', movies=movies, form=form, form_search=form_search, num_paginas=0)



@app.route("/confirmar/<token>")
def confirmar(token):
    my_user = User.query.filter_by(token=token).first()
    if my_user:
        my_user.active = True
        db.session.add(my_user)
        try:
            flash('Su cuenta ha sido activada.', 'success')
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
    else:
        flash('Enlace caducado', 'danger')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))



@app.route("/signup", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = User_form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            email = request.form['email']
            my_user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
            if not my_user:
                if request.form['password1'] == request.form['password2']:
                    my_user = User(request.form['username'], request.form['email'], request.form['password1'])
                    db.session.add(my_user)
                    try:
                        db.session.commit
                        db.session.commit()
                        # Envio de email
                        msg = Message("Hello",
                            sender="no-reply@idecrea.es",
                            recipients=[my_user.email])
                        link_token = f'http://localhost:5000/confirmar/{my_user.token}'
                        msg.html = render_template(
                                'email/confirmar.html',
                                link_token=link_token)
                        mail.send(msg)
                        # Informamos al usuario
                        flash('Le acabamos de enviar un email con las instrucciones. Gracias.', 'success')

                    except:
                        db.session.rollback()
                        flash('Disculpe, ha ocurrido un error.', 'danger')
                    return redirect(url_for('login'))
                else:
                    flash('Los passwords no son iguales', 'danger')
            else:
                flash('El e-mail ya esta registrado', 'danger')
        else:
            # Mostramos errores
            errores = form.errors.items()
            for campo, mensajes in errores:
                for mensaje in mensajes:
                    flash(mensaje, 'danger')
    return render_template('items/signup.html', form=form)

@app.route("/close")
def close_session():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))


@app.route("/like/<movie>")
def add_like(movie):
    movie_like = Movie.query.filter_by(id=movie).first()
    movie_like.like = movie_like.like + 1
    db.session.add(movie_like)
    db.session.commit()
    return ''


@app.route("/perfil", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def perfil():
    form = Perfil_form()
    my_user = User.query.filter_by(id=session['user']).first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Comprobamos si desean cambiar la contraseña
        if request.form['password_anterior'] and request.form['password_nueva']:
            # Comprobamos que la contraseña anterior es igual a la que ya estaba
            if hashlib.md5(request.form['password_anterior'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() == my_user.password:
                # Modificamos
                my_user.password = hashlib.md5(request.form['password_nueva'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                db.session.add(my_user)
                try:
                    db.session.commit()
                    flash('Su contraseña ha sido modificada correctamente', 'success')
                except:
                    db.session.rollback()
            else:
                flash('Su contraseña anterior no es igual. ¿Eres tú?', 'danger')
        # Cambiar el username
        my_user.username = request.form['username']
        db.session.add(my_user)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
    return render_template('items/perfil.html', form=form, user=my_user)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Aquí el Models.py

```
import time
import hashlib
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/imdb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(32))
    avatar = db.Column(db.String(500))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    token = db.Column(db.String(32))
    movie = db.relationship('Movie', backref='user',
                                lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.avatar = 'img/avatars/default.gif'
        self.password = hashlib.md5(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        self.active = False
        self.token = hashlib.md5(str(time.time()).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

class Movie(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    year = db.Column(db.Integer)
    image = db.Column(db.String(500))
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    like = db.Column(db.Integer)
    id_user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __init__(self, name, year, score, ruta, id_user):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.score = score
        self.image = ruta
        self.like = 0
        self.id_user = id_user

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Movies %r>' % self.name
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Dinfecs, cuando necesites agregar código no lo hagas con un enlace externo, esto dificulta la tarea a la gente que pueda responderte y a otros usuarios que tengan tu mismo problema, además en un futuro el enlace puede caer y la pregunta no tendría sentido. Para agregar código simplemente lo copias, en el editor de la pregunta, lo selecionas y pulsas `Ctrl+k` o haces click en el botón `{ }` del editor. Por ser tu primera vez por el sitio te edito yo la pregunta por esta vez :). Por otro lado,  te aconsejo que pongas la traza al completo del error siempre. Saludos.

Comment: Agrega el código de models.py. También hace falta la configuración de la base de datos. Creo que el problema esta en la estructura de tu proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por corregirme y lo siento.
Añadido el models.py y la lista completa de errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error de la librería de flask-sqlachemy en la version 2.2

Instala la version anterior y arreglado.

Para python3

```
pip3 install flask_sqlalchemy==2.1
```

o para python2

```
pip install flask_sqlalchemy==2.1
```